# Deletar registro sem refresh de pagina?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend

Tenho o seguinte Ajax/Jquery para deletar um registro conforme ação de um href.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function apagarRegistro(idTel) {

            var baseurl = '<?php echo $sig_url;?>';

                $.ajax ({

                    url: baseurl+"/sistel/index/apagar?idRegistro="+idTel,
                    type:'POST',

                success:function(res){

                    if (res != 'success') {
                         alert("Registro apagado com sucesso.");
                         history.go(0);
                    }
                }

               });
    }
</script>
```

O problema que eu estou tendo é que após eu efetuar uma consulta na primeira pagina (da paginação) quando eu clico em deletar o arquivo e o mesmo é feito com sucesso, quero que seja dado o refresh na pagina porém apresenta a mensagem para confirmar conforme print aí:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual seria a solução para isso?

Comment: Por que você precisa dar o refresh? Se for para atualizar o registro apagado seria melhor atualizar pelo próprio ajax.

Comment: Pois é, de alguma forma me baguncei então. Pois o código deveria fazer isso. O que acontece é que se não der o refresh o registro não some. #buguei

Comment: Se a tabela onde está o registro estiver sendo chamada via ajax, basta chamar a função que a cria novamente.

Comment: Se os dados estiverem em uma tabela, basta apagar a linha no qual o arquivo deletado estadava. Tudo depende de como você está apresentando esses dados.

Comment: Não entendi bem, no meu caso estou usando o Zend e tenho um método na model que faz o delete.

Comment: Mostra o código aonde voce monta a tabela pra elucidar melhor a pergunta

Comment: A forma de trazer dados é normal com foreach.. a linha que faz ação de apagar é essa que conforme laço tem o ID de cada registro: <?php href="javascript:apagarRegistro(<?php echo $res->idTelefone;?>)"  ?>

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta é, como você está fazendo para exibir a tabela? Em uma `pagina.php` só, ou via `ajax`, montando os dados dinamicamente....

---

- Se for montada em uma página só, a solução seria apagar a linha onde
  estão os dados.
- Agora se você estiver montando a tabela via `Ajax`, basta chamar
  novamente a função que monta a tabela, ai os dados viram
  atualizados...

---

**Tabela montada na página:**

```
function apagarRegistro(idTel){
.
.
.
    success:function(res){
        if (res != 'success') {
            var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
            par.remove();
            alert("Registro apagado com sucesso.");
        }
    }
.
.
.
}
```

---

**Tabela montada por função `AJAX`:**

Em um arquivo `arquivo.html` possuo o seguinte script:

```
<script>
function carregaTabela(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tabela.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#tabela').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function excluir(id){
    resposta = confirm("Deseja realmente excluir esse aluno?");
    if (resposta){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            url: "php/acao.php",
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 1){
                    alert("Excluido com Sucesso!");
//Nessa linha é feita a mágica, toda vez que excluir o registro, ele chamara a função  carregaTabela() novamente
                    carregaTabela();
                }else{
                    alert("Houve algum erro ao excluir!");
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Houve algum erro ao excluir!");
            }
        });
    }
}

</script>
<body onload="carregaTabela()">
<div id="tabela"></div>
</body>
```

A minha página `tabela.php` é simples, apenas possui a tabela formatada com os dados dentro, além disso em cada linha do `foreach` eu adiciono a seguinte coluna:

```
<td style='text-align: center;'><img style='cursor:pointer;' src='delete.png' onclick='excluir(".$id.",".$varIDTeste.")' title='Excluir'></td>
```